# Assigning application roles to user with MicrosoftGraph API fails

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to assign an application role to a user through the Microsoft Graph API but I keep getting the following response :

`Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.`

I am calling this url :`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/the-user-id-goes-here/appRoleAssignments`

and I pass the access token in the authentication header and in the body I pass the principalid (userid), resourceid (the client application id) and appRoleId (the id of the role as defined in the application's manifest).

I have also assigned the AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All permissions to the client application and admin granted consent.

So what am I missing ?  Why do I keep getting this response ?

EDIT
The documentation for this api endpoint is here  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

and the call requires the following permission, which I have added to the application :
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add "Directory.ReadWrite.All" permission which will fix your issue.

Comment: I am confused now. See the edit of my post with screen capture of the documentation. The permission i've added to my application should be enough, right ? Why do I also need Directory.ReadWrite.All ?  This one is not isted.

Comment: Because You are trying to get app role assignments for particular **User**. For accessing users also you need [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions).

Comment: I am not trying to GET the app role. I'm trying to ADD app role assignment for a user with a POST. Does this make a difference ?

Comment: Please test and conform with "Directory.ReadWrite.All" and this permission will be same for updating user.

Comment: I cannot test this right away because it requires Admin Consent, which I cannot do. I don't think I will be allowed to have this privilege as it applies to whole directory.

Comment: I will test from my side and give you the solution soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested in my lab and able to reproduce and fix the issue.

Since, we are trying to get app role assignments for particular User and for accessing users also we need [*permissions*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) ,Please Adding "***Directory.ReadWrite.All***" permission that will fix your issue.

> Note: Users with specific privilege roles can only handle approles.
>   For example Global Administrator, Privileged Role administrator ..etc
>   Please go through [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles#available-roles) for more details.

Comment: I am now wondering if I pass the correct resourceId into the body of the request. I though that resourceId was the Application ID (i.e the Client ID of the registered app) but if I use that one, I get a response that the resource does not exist. If I use the Object ID of the Enterprise Application instead, then I get the Insufficient Privileges message, although now I have added the Directory.ReadWrite.All permission with admin consent. Am I passing the correct resourceID or did I misunderstood something ?

Comment: Hii @Sam,You need to use registered Applications object id as resource id and for principle id also you need to use enterprise apps object id. Client id is not required for this case.Also, I have tested and working fine for me with above permission with post request.please ask your admin to grant consent.

Comment: If I use the registered applications object id as resource id, it complains it does not exists when I call appRoleAssignments. However if I use the Enterprise Application Id, then it works but I get the insufficient privilege message. Admin granted consent already. The application permissions are like in the new screenshot in post above

Comment: could it be related to the authentication token i'm passing to the graph api in the header ? It works fine for reading roles, but maybe the user needs special role to be able to create approles ?

Comment: Yes users with specific privilege can only create approles. If you log in with Global admin role  which is the highest privilege then you can have full control and early do this operation

Comment: what is the minimal privilege for a signed-in user to be able to create approles ?  surely i cannot log in with global admin role, i don't have that kind of privilege

Comment: I've added the Application Administrator role to the signed-in user and finally it is working. I can assign approles  :)   Do you reckon this role is the minimum for being able to add approles ?

Comment: We can say minimum privilege based on role because each role has a purpose.The [role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles#application-administrator) you are using now is good for your current situation.

Comment: can you edit your answer to include the missing role that I had to add to the signed-in user in order to succeed ? This plus the directory.readwrite.all is the complete answer. Thank you so much for helping me, much appreciated !

Comment: Updated my answer